# Error : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _this2.next is not a function in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I got this error Could you please help me to remove this error . I have 4 cases in my application. You may review my step 2 code in case 1. Please help me i am really stuck

```
case 1:
        // code run for step 2

        const reader = new FileReader();
        const storeUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
        reader.onload = function(upload) {
          fetch(`...../api/s3/uploadtoaws`, {
            headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
              userId: storeUser._id,
              type: 'employee',
              content: upload.target.result,
              key: 'e.file.name',
              oldKey: '',
            }),
          })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(res => {
              if (res.error) {
                console.warn(res);
              } else {
                console.warn(res);
                this.next();
              }
            })
            .done();
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(values.picture.file.originFileObj);
        break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> reader.onload = function(upload) {

Since this is a normal function, its value of `this` is determined by how its invoked. I presume that FileReader invokes it with `this` equal to the global object (in non-strict mode) or undefined (in strict mode). Though since i'm not sure how that FileReader code is implemented it could have `this` equal to something else, such as the file reader itself. Either way, later on when you call `this.next`, `this` is not equal to what you think it is.

If you change this to an arrow function, it will get its value of `this` from where its defined.

```
reader.onload = (upload) => {
```

Note that that may not be enough, since it also depends what code is surrounding the example you provided. You may need to turn other functions into arrow functions, and/or use [function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)